# Error installing MySQL on windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-firewall

I uninstalled MySQL 5.7.1 Community from my windows 7 laptop , and now trying to install it again.

But getting error "There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper. (Exception from HRESULT: 0"

Googled around to find this...  http://johnyassa.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/there-are-no-more-endpoints-available-from-the-endpoint-mapper-exception-from-hresult-0x800706d9/ , but not sure if this is the reason , and which subprogram should i enable or disable firewall for ?

Please help

Comment: Have you installed a localhost programm like MAMP, XAMPP, LAMP or so ?

Comment: few months back i uninstalled XAMPP

Comment: have you uninstalled their drivers, too ?